# How can I use gzip for my angular project?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I read some article about decreasing angular project size, in those articles I founded some solution but one of them was Obscure for me and that was gzipped compression, my question is how I can use gzip for my application?

If it helps you, I'm using asp.net core as my back-end technology.

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to install these two dev dependencies

```
 "gulp": "^4.0.0",
"gulp-gzip": "^1.4.2",
```

Create a postbuild script in your package.json

```
"postbuild": "gulp compress",
```

Create a gulpfile.js file at the same level of package.json file with the following code

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gzip = require('gulp-gzip');

gulp.task('compress', function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(gulp.src(['./dist/**/*.*'])
        .pipe(gzip())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist')));

    })
});
```

Whenever you build your project this postbuild command will compress the files for after the build.

Comment: Is it possible to gzip when running `ng serve`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gzip-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gzip-all)

I'm currently using this version

```
"gzip-all": "^1.0.0"
```

So my build command will be

```
ng build --prod && gzip-all \"dist/*.*\"
```

So gzip-all will gzip every file in dist folder

Comment: After installing this module and running that for my project I have some .gz file in dist folder for some files. 
Should I delete the primary file and maintain the .gz file or not?
example: I have main.js and main.js.gz file in the dist folder, should I delete main.js and maintain just the main.js.gz or not?